# Paraview : Glew could not be initialized

Tags: python, glew, paraview

I am trying to run a simple code for paraview from jupyter notebook as following:

```
from paraview.simple import *
cone = Cone()
Show(cone)
Render()
```

But this gives me an error

> ERROR:In/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/paraview_1532760595263/work/VTK/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx,
>   line 781 vtkOSOpenGLRenderWindow (0x556661755060): GLEW could not be
>   initialized.

The error remains the same when I run it from a python shell. I also installed paraview using conda. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Maybe it's related to graphics driver? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yeah , that was my initial diagnosis too. But it didnt work. Tried removing redundant vtk version installed due to other another build of paraview but that didnt work as well.